# Error in node-modules/dotenv.main.js in react app

Tags: reactjs

ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 25:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL PC\OneDrive\Documents\Newss\newsapp\node_modules\dotenv\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
- install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

I am getting this same error again and again after compiling the react app
I tried debugging it but it is still showing the same error
How can I fix it? Can someone please help

I tried installing os-browserify
then created a new file config-override.js
`const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = function override(config) {`your text`
c
config.resolve.fallback = fallback;
"os" ; require.resolve("os-browserify/browser");
config.plugins = (config.plugins || []).concat([
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
process: 'process/browser',
Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer']
})
])
return config;
}`
still it is not working
what can i do?